# Combinations. You have 6 friends to whom you want to distribute 20 sugar cookies, How many ways can you distribute the cookies?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

a)How many ways can you distribute the cookies? 
Is it simply ${20 \choose 6}$

b)What if you need to give 
(i) at least $4$ cookies to Joe and at least $5$ cookies
to Sam? Would this be "give $4$ to Joe then $5$ to Sam" and then ${11 \choose 6}$ for the rest?

(ii) at least $4$ cookies to Joe and at most $4$ cookies to Sam?
"give $4$ to Sam" and then ${16 \choose 6}$?

c)Suppose you want to make sure that at least one friend gets $5$ cookies.
Are $20$ cookies enough? How many more would you need and why?
No you would need at least $25$ cookies because of the Pigeon hole principle.

I'm not quite sure about combinations yet. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please use *MathJax* for all formulas and math symbols

Answer (score 2):

> How many ways can you distribute $20$ sugar cookies to six friends?

Let $x_j$ be the number of cookies given to the $j$th friend, where $1 \leq j \leq 6$.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 20 \tag{1}$$
Equation 1 is an equation in the nonnegative integers (since we have not specified that each friend receives at least one cookie).  A particular solution to equation 1 corresponds to the placement of five addition signs in a row of twenty ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 5$, $x_4 = 4$, $x_5 = 2$, and $x_6 = 6$.  The number of such solutions is 
$$\binom{20 + 5}{5} = \binom{25}{5}$$
since we must choose which $5$ of the $25$ positions required for $20$ ones and $5$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Since a particular solution of the equation in the nonnegative integers
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_k = n \tag{2}$$
corresponds to the insertion of $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones, equation 2 has 
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers since we must choose which $k - 1$ of the $n + k - 1$ positions required for $n$ ones and $k - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

> How many ways can you distribute $20$ sugar cookies to six friends if you must give at least $4$ cookies to Joe and at least $5$ cookies to Sam?

Give Joe four cookies and Sam five cookies.  That leaves you with eleven cookies to distribute to six friends, so you must find the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 11$$
in the nonnegative integers.

> How many ways can you distribute $20$ sugar cookies to six friends if you give at least four cookies to Joe and at most four cookies to Sam?

Give Joe four cookies.  We will worry about Sam later.  That leaves you with $16$ cookies to distribute to six friends, so you must find the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 16 \tag{3}$$
in the nonnegative integers.

From these, we must remove those solutions in which Sam receives more than four cookies.  Let $x_6$ be the number of cookies that Sam receives.  Suppose that Sam receives more than four cookies.  Then $x_6' = x_6 - 5$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_6' + 5$ for $x_6$ in equation 3 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6' + 5 & = 16\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_4 + x_6' & = 11 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Equation 4 is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  To find the desired answer, you must subtract the number of nonnegative integer solutions of equation 4 from the number of nonnegative integer solutions of equation 3.

> Suppose you want to make sure at least one friend receives five cookies.  Are $20$ cookies enough?  How many more would you need and why?

Your reasoning is correct.  Just note that you need to state how many more cookies you would need.

Answer (score 0):

for a). Surely it is actually $C(25,5) + C(24,4) + C(23,3) + ... C(20,0)$ because you can imagine placing 5 slots in between 20 cookies to separate each individual's share. The number of ways is then $C(25,5)$ but we need to include when such and such a person has no cookies i.e. there are 4 slots etc. This is assuming the 6 people are unidentical so the distribution 1,1,9,9 is not the same as 9,9,1,1.

Comment: Did you mean in between $20$ cookies?

Comment: yes i have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

The cookies are not distinguishable so we need to use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). In (a) we seek the number of integral solutions to 
$$
x_1+\dotsb+x_6=20\quad(x_i\geq0)
$$
while in b(i) the number of solutions to
$$
x_1+\dotsb+x_6=20\quad(x_1\geq4,x_2\geq5,x_i\geq0 )
$$
while in b(ii) the number of solutions to

$$
x_1+\dotsb+x_6=20\quad(x_1\geq4,x_2\leq4,x_i\geq0 ).
$$
The first two can be manipulated quite easily to fit the formula. The third one requires inclusion, exclusion.